# Switch Case - not all cases work

Tags: php, switch-statement

At the moment I am writing a calendar. According to the chosen motn (`$monthnum`), I store the abbreviated month name (`$monthabbr`) in a database. For that I use a switch-case construct. It works for all months, except for 08-August and 09-September. Since I used the same code for all months, I don't know why it's not working. I am close to the edge to start all over again, but before that I'll better ask if you see an error.

```
switch( $monthnum ) {
            case 01:
                $monthabbr = 'Jan';
                break;
            case 02:
                $monthabbr = 'Feb';
                break;
            case 03:
                $monthabbr = 'Mär';
                break;
            case 04:
                $monthabbr = 'Apr';
                break;
            case 05:
                $monthabbr = 'Mai';
                break;
            case 06:
                $monthabbr = 'Jun';
                break;
            case 07:
                $monthabbr = 'Jul';
                break;
            case 08:
                $monthabbr = 'Aug';
                break;
            case 09:
                $monthabbr = 'Sep';
                break;
            case 10:
                $monthabbr = 'Okt';
                break;
            case 11:
                $monthabbr = 'Nov';
                break;
            case 12:
                $monthabbr = 'Dez';
                break;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change `01`, `02`, ..., `09` to just `1`, `2`, ..., `9` (drop the zeros).

---

By starting an integer literal with a `0` indicates that it should be interpreted as an **octal number** (a number in base 8).

For octal numbers the digits `8` and `9` are illegal.

**Further reading:**

- [PHP Manual: Integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php)

---

(Btw, you may want to consider **using an array or a map from integer to string**, and just look up the string using something like `monthAbbrs[$monthnum]`)

Comment: Right. And therefore 08 and 09 are invalid, 10 is 8 (dec) and 11 is 9 (dec).

Comment: 010 is 8 (dec) and 011 is 9 (dec), 10 is 10 (dec) and 11 is 11 (dec)

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks! I didn't new about the 0 at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this issue by using quotes

```
switch($date){
    case "01": $month = "January"; break;
    case "02": $month = "February"; break;
    case "03": $month = "March"; break;
    case "04": $month = "April"; break;
    case "05": $month = "May"; break;
    case "06": $month = "June"; break;
    case "07": $month = "July"; break;
    case "08": $month = "August"; break;
    case "09": $month = "September"; break;
    case "10": $month = "October"; break;
    case "11": $month = "November"; break;
    case "12": $month = "December"; break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what the purpose is but a better way is to parse your date

```
$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );
$phpdate = strtotime( $mysqldate );
```

see [here](http://www.richardlord.net/blog/dates-in-php-and-mysql)

and then format it in the way you like:

```
// Prints something like: Monday 8th of August 2005 03:12:46 PM
echo date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
```

see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: Indeed, you can do it like that. But for my purpose, you can select any date using a drop-down menu.